# Why my program runs faster on 1 thread than on 8. C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, parallel-processing

Please look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
    void operator()(Iterator begin, Iterator end, T& result)
    {
        result = std::accumulate(begin, end, result);
    }    
};

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
int accumulate_all(Iterator begin, Iterator end, T& init)
{
    auto numOfThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(numOfThreads);
    auto step = std::distance(begin, end) / numOfThreads;
    std::vector<int> results(numOfThreads,0);
    for(int i=0; i<numOfThreads-1; ++i)
    {
        auto block_end = begin;
        std::advance(block_end, step);
        threads[i] = std::thread(accumulate_block<Iterator, T>(), begin, block_end, std::ref(results[i]));
        begin = block_end;
    }
    threads[numOfThreads-1] = std::thread(accumulate_block<Iterator, T>(), begin, end, std::ref(results[numOfThreads-1]));
    for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    return accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0);
}

int main()
{ 
   int x=0;
   std::vector<int> V(20000000,1);
   auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   //std::accumulate(std::begin(V), std::end(V), x); singe threaded option
   std::cout<<accumulate_all(std::begin(V), std::end(V), x);
   auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << "process took: "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
    << " nanoseconds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run on concurrent version (basically on 8 threads because my  `std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` returns 8)
the output is: process took: `8895404 nanoseconds`.

But the single threaded options output is: `process took: 124 nanoseconds`

Can anyone explain this strange behavior??

Comment: Doesn't the main thread count as a thread?

Comment: Are you sure the counting isn't simply optimized out?

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess so, and?

Comment: @spectras, I am not. How can I check that?

Comment: So you have one more than the hinted at hardware concurrency...

Comment: @StoryTeller thats even worse. Whats your point?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan by looking at generated assembly. But here some simple math could be enough: a 4GHz cpu does 1 cycle every .25ns (and most instructions use more than one). There is no way it could go through 20000000 elements in 124ns. The counting clearly is optimized out in the single-thread version.

Comment: I have run this on ideone.com, do you know how to turn off optimizations there?

Comment: try adding `std::cout<<` even in the single thread version ;)

Comment: @Eduard Rostomyan Yep.. you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler removes the call to `std::accumulate` because it does not have side effects and the result is not used.

Fix:

```
auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(V), std::end(V), x); // singe threaded option

// At the very end.
std::cout << sum << '\n';
```